# How to specify delimiter between JSON objects in Kinesis Firehose

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, delimiter, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

As far as I understand, it is possible to specify delimiter on Firehose as long as you activate Dynamic Partitioning. You can see "New line delimiter" option under the Dynamic partitioning section.
However, I need to specify a delimiter without using Dynamic Partitioning. I cannot see this option anywhere. Is it possible to achive that?

Note: I am trying to find a built-in solution other than appending manually `data + "\n"` in producer application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup [lambda function for firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-kinesisfirehose.html) which is going to process the records and add new line to them.

Comment: Does it cause delay in Firehose sink?

Comment: @mhmtersy Depends on how intenstive are your lambda transformation. FH is not real-time anyway, it does not really matter match.

Comment: I see the JSON records in s3 bucket, delivered by Firehose, being concatenated to each other. Athena can only parse the first record for each s3 file. Does it mean I have to setup lambda to transform the record so that Athena can read it correcly?

Comment: @UMR Yes, you need to setup a lambda function or append "\n" at the end of each json record in your producer application.